# how to ignore case in sep argument for tidyr::separate()

Tags: r, tidyr

If I want to separate a string into a few new columns based on a letter, how can I ignore the case of that letter? `regex("h", ignore_case = TRUE)` is not working in `tidyr::separate()` and the string is not being separated on capital H's. However the regex argument works fine in `str_split()`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)

tibble(x = "I hear Henry has Heads") %>% 
    separate(
        x, 
        into = c("h1", "h2", "h3"), 
        sep = regex("h", ignore_case = TRUE), 
        extra = "merge"
    )

str_split("I hear Henry has heads", pattern = regex("h", ignore_case = TRUE))
```

Comment: You could make the regex `[Hh]`, though I suspect there's another way to do it

Comment: @alistaire, yes I could use "[Hh]" or "H|h". I was curious if there was a way to use ignore_case = TRUE or a similar regex function to ignore case generally in separate().

Comment: `(?i)h` is the regex-standard way. Actually `base::strsplit` also lacks an `ignore.case` argument

Comment: It seems the way `regex()` signals its `ignore_case` argument is through a `case_insensitive` argument, which `tidyr` is ostensibly ignoring. You may want to file an issue with `tidyr`

Comment: Yeah, looking at the source, `separate.data.frame` uses a function called `str_split_fixed()` (defined internally and not equivalent to `stringr::str_split_fixed()`) that ignore the attributes set by `regex()`

Comment: @MichaelChirico not sure if you're still around, but this really should be posted as an answer to the question if you see this. It certainly helped me!

Answer (score 1):

This now works with the [`separate_wider_delim` function](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/separate_wider_delim.html):

```
tibble(x = "I hear Henry has Heads") %>% 
  separate_wider_delim(
    x, 
    regex("h", ignore_case = TRUE), 
    names_sep = "")

# A tibble: 1 × 5
  x1    x2     x3      x4    x5   
  <chr> <chr>  <chr>   <chr> <chr>
1 "I "  "ear " "enry " "as " eads
```